# how to find out whether a link is handled by a javascript or uses the href url

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

i'm trying to debug a link, but the opened url is a bit different from the one given in the href attribute. it seems like some javascript is used to handle the link after a click event.

unfortunately the js file is very huge and unreadable, so i can't find the place, that changes or handles my link.

is there any possibility to debug this with firebug or chrome developer tools?

thanks!

peter

Answer (score 1):

This is involved process, depends how much is hidden. You can just use "inspect" button in firebug on the link. Once you click it it will show you the source code. It could reference the javascript directly or it could just have an id or class and the javascript has an event bound to this id class.

Look at the url to see if there is something like onclick="javascriptFunctionName()". If not - look for the js referencing class name or id of the element and subscribing to events.

Comment: Click the Script tab in Firebug, enable it if necessary. Click the Pause button, then click the link in question. It should show you exactly what JavaScript is attached to it.